# How to customize Last-Modified Header in Joomla?

Tags: seo, joomla, http-headers, last-modified

Even in the latest Joomla 1.5 Last-Modified Header is non-customizable and returns current date, which is imho against seo-basics. Does any one know how (or component) to make Joomla 1.5 return Last-Modified header based on last modified article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JResponse::setHeader( 'Last-Modified', $yourDateHere );` should work. However, if you want to add this without hacking `com_content`, you'll need to build a plugin that will detect when `com_content` is being called, then retrieve the article from the database to get the modified date on the article.

Answer (score 0):

**@All**
Feel free to download and test lite version of plugin "[Last-Modified Any Content Lite](https://www.yunoshev.com/11-last-modified-any-content-lite)". This one allows you to send right header information about last-modified date of page for search bots to increase indexing your websites.